# How to convert hex to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I copied and pasted this binary data out of sql server, which I am unable to query at this time.

```
0xBAC893CAB8B7FE03C927417A2A3F6A60BD30FF35E250011CB25507EBFCD5223B
```

How do I convert it back to a byte array in c#?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this:

```
using System;

public static class Parser
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        string hex = "0xBAC893CAB8B7FE03C927417A2A3F6A6"
                     + "0BD30FF35E250011CB25507EBFCD5223B";
        byte[] parsed = ParseHex(hex);
        // Just for confirmation...
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(parsed));
    }

    public static byte[] ParseHex(string hex)
    {
        int offset = hex.StartsWith("0x") ? 2 : 0;
        if ((hex.Length % 2) != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length: " + hex.Length);
        }
        byte[] ret = new byte[(hex.Length-offset)/2];

        for (int i=0; i < ret.Length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = (byte) ((ParseNybble(hex[offset]) << 4) 
                             | ParseNybble(hex[offset+1]));
            offset += 2;
        }
        return ret;
    }        

    static int ParseNybble(char c)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            return c-'0';
        }
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        {
            return c-'A'+10;
        }
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        {
            return c-'a'+10;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
    }
}
```

(EDIT: Now slightly more efficient - no substrings required...)

It's possible that `ParseNybble` could be more efficient. For example, a switch/case *may* be more efficient:

```
    static int ParseNybble(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
            case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                return c-'0';
            case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
                return c-'A'+10;
            case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
                return c-'a'+10;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
    }
```

or possibly a lookup array:

```
    // Omitted for brevity... I'm sure you get the gist
    private static readonly int[] NybbleLookup = BuildLookup();

    private int ParseNybble(char c)
    {
        if (c > 'f')
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
        }
        int ret = NybbleLookup[c];
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex digit: " + c);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I haven't benchmarked any of these, and I've no idea which would be the fastest. The current solution is probably the simplest though.

Comment: why do you prefer parsing each nybble instead of one byte at a time?
is it because you are more efficient by not creating new strings each time?

Comment: Yes. Why not? It's efficient, and this is the kind of code you only need once in a library somewhere. Creating n*2 strings to create a byte array of length n seems pretty wasteful when the alternative is so easy.

Comment: Sorry, creating n strings, not n*2. But each of those strings will be about 20 bytes or so, which seems rather a large bloat factor. All gen0 of course, but easily avoidable.

Comment: +1. I made mine to be a little more "straight-forward" but I think yours is much more efficient.  Maybe I'll incorporate the ParseNybble. It would be pretty easy to merge that into my exisiting code.

Comment: Also, instead of doing the substring, you could just do an offset into the start value of the loop (i = offset...) and the same for length (length = (hex/2) - 1) if hex starts with "0x"

Comment: @Erich: Absolutely. It would just complicate things a little... I wanted to keep this *quite* efficient but still simple. Might see what I can do though :)

Comment: Okay, so I couldn't resist doing a bit of tweaking :)

Answer (score 6):

Consider leveraging a Framework class that already exposes the ability to perform hex conversion, XmlReader for example:

```
public static byte[] HexToBytes(this string hexEncodedBytes, int start, int end)
{
    int length = end - start;
    const string tagName = "hex";
    string fakeXmlDocument = String.Format("<{1}>{0}</{1}>",
                           hexEncodedBytes.Substring(start, length),
                           tagName);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fakeXmlDocument));
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings());
    int hexLength = length / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[hexLength];
    reader.ReadStartElement(tagName);
    reader.ReadContentAsBinHex(result, 0, hexLength);
    return result;
}
```

usage:

```
string input = "0xBAC893CAB8B7FE03C927417A2A3F6A60BD30FF35E250011CB255";
byte[] bytes = input.HexToBytes(2, input.Length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
string hexnum = "0000000F"; // Represents 15
int value = int.Parse(hexnum, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

All you have to remember to do is for an int to divide the hex number up into groups of 8 hex digits (hex are 4 bits each, and CLR int type is 32 bits, hence 8 digits per int).  There's also a byte.Parse() that works the same, but pass in two hex digits at a time.

Comment: You still need to convert to byte[]. BitConverter would do it.  What if the sequence is not a multiple of sizeof(int)?

Comment: @Erich - Ya, that's why in my last sentence I mentioned the byte.Parse() method too.

Comment: Doesn't work for strings of the length specified in the question, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
    public byte[] ParseHexString(string text)
    {
        if ((text.Length % 2) != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid length: " + text.Length);
        }

        if (text.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            text = text.Substring(2);
        }

        int arrayLength = text.Length / 2;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[arrayLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            byteArray[i] = byte.Parse(text.Substring(i*2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        return byteArray;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Sure, other answers have better character handling and might have better performance, but this answer solves the problem in a way that is easy for beginners to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify this a little bit (for example, skip over the first two characters), but it does handle spaces in the string:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Decodes a hex string, ignoring all non-hex characters, and stores
    /// the decodes series of bytes into the shared buffer. This returns
    /// the number of bytes that were decoded.
    /// <para>Hex characters are [0-9, a-f, A-F].</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hexString">String to parse into bytes.</param>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer into which to store the decoded binary data.</param>
    /// <returns>The number of bytes decoded.</returns>
    private static int DecodeHexIntoBuffer(string hexString, byte[] buffer)
    {
        int count = 0;

        bool haveFirst = false;
        bool haveSecond = false;
        char first = '0';
        char second = '0';

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!haveFirst)
            {
                first = hexString[i];
                haveFirst = char.IsLetterOrDigit(first);

                // we have to continue to the next iteration
                // or we will miss characters
                continue;
            }

            if (!haveSecond)
            {
                second = hexString[i];
                haveSecond = char.IsLetterOrDigit(second);
            }

            if (haveFirst && haveSecond)
            {
                string hex = "" + first + second;

                byte nextByte;
                if (byte.TryParse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out nextByte))
                {
                    // store the decoded byte into the next slot of the buffer
                    buffer[count++] = nextByte;
                }

                // reset the flags
                haveFirst = haveSecond = false;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's an easier way to convert two characters at a time to a byte:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will convert a hex-encoded string to byte data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hexData">The hex-encoded string to convert</param>
    /// <returns>The bytes that make up the hex string</returns>
    public static byte[] FromHex(string hexData)
    {
        List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
        string byteSet = string.Empty;
        int stringLen = hexData.Length;
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLen; i = i + 2)
        {
            length = (stringLen - i) > 1 ? 2 : 1;
            byteSet = hexData.Substring(i, length);

            // try and parse the data
            data.Add(Convert.ToByte(byteSet, 16 /*base*/));
        } // next set

        return data.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slow yet fun way :D

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace(" ", "");
    hex = hex.Replace(":", "");
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
            .ToArray();
}
```

-jD

Answer (score 0):

I use this for C#, from similar code in Java.

```
    private static char[] hexdigit = "0123456789abcdef".ToCharArray();

    public static string hexlify(string argbuf) {
        int arglen = argbuf.Length;
        char[] argca = argbuf.ToCharArray ();
        StringBuilder retbuf = new StringBuilder(arglen * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < arglen; i++) {
            char ch = argca[i];
            retbuf.Append(hexdigit[(ch >> 4) & 0xF]);
            retbuf.Append(hexdigit[ch & 0xF]);
        }
        return retbuf.ToString();
    }

    public static string unhexlify(string argbuf) {
        int arglen = argbuf.Length;
        if (arglen % 2 != 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("Odd-length string");
        }
        char[] argca = argbuf.ToCharArray ();
        StringBuilder retbuf = new StringBuilder(arglen / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < arglen; i += 2) {
            int top = Convert.ToInt32 (argca[i].ToString (), 16);
            int bot = Convert.ToInt32 (argca[i + 1].ToString (), 16);
            if (top == -1 || bot == -1) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("Non-hexadecimal digit found");
            }
            retbuf.Append((char) ((top << 4) + bot));
        }
        return retbuf.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one is cute!

```
string source = "Hello World!";
 using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
 {
     //From String to byte array
     byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
     byte[] hashBytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
     string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);
     Console.WriteLine("The SHA256 hash of " + source + " is: " + hash);
 }
```