# C# convert hex into ip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hex, ip

i have hex values in the format of 4a0e94ca etc, and i need to convert them into IP's, how can i do this in C# ?

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-int-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: Sorry sniper, I see you're new here. Please search questions before posting a duplicate. The link to the answer you're looking for is above

Comment: Whether that's a duplicate depends on how you define an IP, and what the output is (I assume it's to be converted to a string).

Comment: Granted. I missed that, however I do feel the answer would be very similar.

Comment: I agree, but at the same time the bitwise math componen that silky posted helps sniperX understand what's happening behind the scenes (which you don't get in that other question). That's just my opinion though!

Comment: Got to agree I liked that answer

Answer (score 16):

If the values represent IPv4 addresses you can use the [`long.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3.aspx) method and pass the result to the [IPAddress constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13180abx.aspx):

```
var ip = new IPAddress(long.Parse("4a0e94ca", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```

If they represent IPv6 addresses you should [convert the hex value to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array) and then use [this IPAddress constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx) to construct the IPAddress.

Comment: Seems like the best way to me

Comment: Note - "var" will only work in .Net framework 3.5
 or higher.

Comment: I think it should be noted, that this will only work when executed on a big endian system.

Answer (score 3):

Well, take the format of an IP in this form:

```
192.168.1.1
```

To get it into a single number, you take each part, OR it together, while shifting it to the left, 8 bits.

```
long l = 192 | (168 << 8) | (1 << 16) | (1 << 24);
```

Thus, you can reverse this process for your number.

Like so:

```
int b1 = (int) (l & 0xff);
int b2 = (int) ((l >> 8) & 0xff);
int b3 = (int) ((l >> 16) & 0xff);
int b4 = (int) ((l >> 24) & 0xff);
```

-- Edit

Other posters probably have 'cleaner' ways of doing it in C#, so probably use that in production code, but I do think the way I've posted is a nice way to learn the format of IPs.

Comment: +1 - I believe knowing the bitwise math is probably the most important part of converting integers to IPs (and vice versa), even if your language does it for you.

Comment: @Matthew: While I agree knowing Bitwise math is useful, most languages that are C derived have the function inet_ntop and inet_pton for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Sure, but I think it's good to know how those functions *work*. Each to his own though, some people aren't as excited as I am about what's happening at the lower levels :)

Answer (score 2):

Check [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-int-to-hex-and-back-again)

```
    var ip = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
    int.Parse(hexValue.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
    int.Parse(hexValue.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
    int.Parse(hexValue.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
    int.Parse(hexValue.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Comment: That is a pretty decent way, but maybe not the fastest.  Still, +1.

Comment: while this is a neat way to do it, it doesn't work for all cases i.e. 192.168.1.1. Since the solution will throw an error after chopping it into 19.21.68.11