# String Hex to Bool and String Hex to String ASCII conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Details about the application:

- Developed under Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10)
- Designed on `UWP` platform with `C#` & `XAML` language

My application receive a frame from a remote server. After receiving the frame, I decode all received information, it's here that I have a problem.

Data received (hexa) : `CA0000000100000030000000010000003137322E31362E3233392E343100000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Code:

```
int _IndexLecture = 0;
bool _PRIORITE;
string _ABONNE;

_TraitementString = _Decode.Substring(_IndexLecture + 8, 2);
_VOIE = Convert.ToSByte(_TraitementString, 16);

_TraitementString = _Decode.Substring(_IndexLecture + 24, 2);
_PRIORITE = Convert.ToBoolean(_TraitementString);

_TraitementString = _Decode.Substring(_IndexLecture + 32, 64);
_ABONNE = Convert.ToString(_TraitementString);
```

Obtained result :

```
_VOIE = 1
_PRIORITE = 
_ABONNE =
```

Exepected result :

```
_VOIE = 1
_PRIORITE = TRUE
_ABONNE = "172.16.239.41"
```

How can I pass my `hex string` to `bool` and `ASCII string` to find the right values?

Comment: It looks almost correct. You should be able to debug most of it, e.g. Convert.ToBoolean("01") throws exception and could be written as _PRIORITE = _IndexLecture == "01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String Hex to Bool and String Hex to String ASCII conversion

The reason why `_PRIORITE` is not correct, because `_IndexLecture` is string type. you could not pass such "01" string parameter to `ToBoolean(sting value)` method, you can only pass "true" or "false" string parameter. Please use the following method to replace.

```
_TraitementString = _Decode.Substring(_IndexLecture + 24, 2);   
_PRIORITE = Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(_TraitementString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```

> How to pass hex string to `IPAddress`.

You could refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355163/7254781). And please note Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) defines an IP address as a 32-bit number. So, it can expressed in 8-bit hexadecimal numbers. Please check if `_TraitementString`is correct.

```
var ip = new IPAddress(long.Parse("4a0e94cb", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```