# convertion of hexadecimal into ipaddress in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion, format, hex

I need a logic how to convert hexadecimal to IP(IPV4) address
for example

```
6F6F6F6F(HEXADECIMAL) - 111.111.111.111(IPADDRESS)
FFFFFFFF(HEXADECIMAL) - 255.255.255.255(IPADDRESS)
```

Comment: Are the values big-endian or little-endian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* to query the original string. The query can be

1. Split original string into chunks of size `2`
2. Convert each chunk into `int` value
3. Join all these `int`'s into the final string

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "6F6F6F6F";

string address = string.Join(".", source
  .Chunk(2)
  .Select(chunk => Convert.ToInt32(new string(chunk), 16)));
```

Demo:

```
using System.Linq;

...

static string MyConvert(string source) => string.Join(".", source
  .Chunk(2)
  .Select(chunk => Convert.ToInt32(new string(chunk), 16)));

string[] tests = {
  "6F6F6F6F",
  "FFFFFFFF",
};

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test}(HEXADECIMAL) - {MyConvert(test)}(IPADDRESS)"));

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
6F6F6F6F(HEXADECIMAL) - 111.111.111.111(IPADDRESS)
FFFFFFFF(HEXADECIMAL) - 255.255.255.255(IPADDRESS)
```

**Edit:** Reverse can be *Linq* based as well:

1. We split the source by `.`
2. Parse each `item` to `int` and format as hexadecimal with 2 mandatory digits
3. Concat all these chunks into the `result` string

```
string source = "123.45.67.221";

string result = string.Concat(source
  .Split('.')
  .Select(item => int.Parse(item).ToString("X2")));
```

**Edit 2:** You can use `GroupBy` instead of `Chunk` in case of old .net versions:

```
string address = string.Join(".", source
  .Select((item, index) => new { item = item, group = index / 2 })
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.group, pair => pair.item)
  .Select(group => Convert.ToInt32(new string(group.ToArray()), 16)));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9U2Z1w)

Comment: sir for ipaddress to hexadecimal conversion  also can we use linq and make it short rather writing for loop if so could u share in linq how we can implement ipaddress to hexadecimal conversion

Comment: @satya: Yes, we can use Linq for reverse (IP Address to Hexadecimal) as well; I've edited the answer

Comment: thank u so much sir for all the support but iam facing some issue with chunk it is not supporting i used namespace linq too any other alternate method using linq

Comment: sir am getting string does not contain definition for chunk am i missing anything or can u suggest any alternate

Comment: @satya: `Chunk` is a Linq *extension method*, please fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9U2Z1w

Comment: checked sir in .net framework chunk is not supporting quite a old project is there any alternate for chunk

Comment: @satya: you can use `GroupBy` instead of `Chunk` (please, see my 2nd edit)

Answer (score 2):

Hi the same question in this Link:

[C# convert hex into ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355147/c-sharp-convert-hex-into-ip)

If the values represent IPv4 addresses you can use the long.Parse method and pass the result to the IPAddress constructor:

```
var ip = new IPAddress(long.Parse("4a0e94ca", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just roll a simple function that gets the job done, like this:

```
public string ToDecimalIp(ReadOnlySpan<char> hexIp)
{
    return @$"{byte.Parse(hexIp.Slice(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}.
        {byte.Parse(hexIp.Slice(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}.
        {byte.Parse(hexIp.Slice(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)},
        {byte.Parse(hexIp.Slice(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}";
}
```

Of course you need to take care of input validation if you're not in control, but I leave that up to you.