# Is there a C# equivalent to Python's unhexlify?

Tags: c#, python, binary, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert hex to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array)

I'm searching for a python compatible method in C# to convert hex to binary.  I've reversed a hash in Python by doing this:

```
import sha
import base64
import binascii

hexvalue = "5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8"
binaryval = binascii.unhexlify(hexvalue)
print base64.standard_b64encode(binaryval)
>> W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```

So far all of the various Hex2Binary C# methods I've found end up throwing OverflowExceptions:

```
static string Hex2Binary(string hexvalue)
{
    string binaryval = "";
    long b = Convert.ToInt64(hexvalue, 16);
    binaryval = Convert.ToString(b);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(binaryval);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

Anybody got a tip on how to produce a C# method to match the python output?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array

Comment: (Use Convert.ToBase64String with the resulting byte array, btw.)

Comment: It's not a duplicate IMO, this is specific as to compatibility between Python and C#.  The answer may be the same, but the question (which others may stumble upon) is certainly different.

Comment: And now they'll stumble upon this question and immediately see a link to the existing question! This is why we keep duplicate questions around on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This value is too big for a long (64bits), that's why you get an OverflowException.

But it's very easy to convert hex to binary byte by byte (well, nibble by nibble actually) :

```
static string Hex2Binary(string hexvalue)
{
    StringBuilder binaryval = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i < hexvalue.Length; i++)
    {
        string byteString = hexvalue.Substring(i, 1);
        byte b = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
        binaryval.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(4, '0'));
    }
    return binaryval.ToString();
}
```

EDIT: the method above converts to binary, not to base64. This one converts to base64 :

```
static string Hex2Base64(string hexvalue)
{
    if (hexvalue.Length % 2 != 0)
        hexvalue = "0" + hexvalue;
    int len = hexvalue.Length / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        string byteString = hexvalue.Substring(2 * i, 2);
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Now do it for the opposite endian?  :)

Comment: does he NEED to convert it to the opposite endian? Only do it if it's needed I say ;-)

Comment: i needs to be incremented by 2, not 1 I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your hexadecimal string into two-digit groups, and then use byte.parse to convert them to bytes. Use the NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier for that, for example:

```
byte.Parse("3F", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

The following routine will convert a hex string to a byte array:

```
private byte[] Hex2Binary(string hex)
{
    var chars = hex.ToCharArray();
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    for(int index = 0; index < chars.Length; index += 2) {
        var chunk = new string(chars, index, 2);
        bytes.Add(byte.Parse(chunk, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
    }
    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```