# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider using hex key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, 3des

I am using TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt a series of bytes in C#. The key which is passed to  me is in like this `FFC7B905AD6ACB57D662115FD65FA338` which i believe is a hex. How can i get this value into `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Key` property which accepts a byte array or how do i copy this value to a byte array so that i can pass to key property.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse the hex to a byte array - nothing to do with encryption, really.

There are lots of bits of sample code to do that here on Stack Overflow, including [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array).

(Not closing this question as a duplicate, as it's not *quite* a duplicate - it's really about understanding that it's a matter of parsing to a byte array first.)