# Hex to byte[] in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, arrays

Assume there is a string `hexString = "0x12"` or `"0x45"` etc. How can I convert the string to another byte[] as below. Thanks.

```
byte[] myByte = new byte[2];
myByte[0] = 0x1;
myByte[1] = 0x2;
```

or

```
myByte[0] = 0x4;
myByte[1] = 0x5;
```

When I try to concatenate the substring as below,

```
myByte[0] = '0x' + '4'; // Show compile error. It doesn't work.
```

I don't know how to fix it. thanks.
etc.

Comment: So you want to store each hex digit in its own byte, instead of the more natural two hex digits per byte representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are looking for something like this?

```
string hex = "0123456789abcdef";

string input = "0x45";
Debug.Assert(Regex.Match(input, "^0x[0-9a-f]{2}$").Success);

byte[] result = new byte[2];
result[0] = (byte)hex.IndexOf(input[2]);
result[1] = (byte)hex.IndexOf(input[3]);

// result[0] == 0x04
// result[1] == 0x05
```

Comment: Actually, string hex = "0x45" (there is not need string `input` again.). And I need take out `4` and `5`. and build new `0x4` and `0x5` as the members of `result`

Comment: Too complex, beyond what I need. :-)

Comment: @Nano HE: Then you should explain in more detail what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for it first?
Try this: [How to convert hex to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: I thought, there is a little different on my question. I am not need convert the whole Hex string to byte[]. What I need is take out the individual number from the hex numberic string, and linked with '0x' before each of them as invidual hex number.

Comment: @Nano: What? If you just want to take a part of the string use `hexString.Substring()` [{msdn}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx). If you want to split the string into many, you can use `string.Split()`[{msdn}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: I updated on my post. I want to concatenate the substring actually.