# Decrypt TCP payload

Tags: encryption, payload

I'm trying to decrypt the payload of a tcp package.
I'm given a key, which is a string of 64 characters, looks like a hex stream, and a "password" (string 8 chars).
I'm told that the encryption algorithm is probably AES.

That's all information given :)
I have tried a few online decryption tools but the results are not understandable.

Do I have enough information to properly decrypt this?
How do I properly convert the 64 bytes string to a key
If anyone would point me in a direction on how to do this in .NET that would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think you have enough information to decrypt the payload. Assuming the "password" is not a red herring, you would need to generate the encryption key out of the password using a key generation function, e.g. PBKDF2. In that case the hex stream could be salt for the key generation function. To unhexlify the hex stream, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854012/how-to-convert-hex-to-a-byte-array . The hex stream could also be the key directly (32bytes, i.e. 256bit is the correct key size for AES256). You also have to find out which blockcipher mode was used for encryption (CBC?).

Comment: With the amount of information given we can only guess, so I'm closing this question as "unclear what you are asking".